# How to default the option list when editing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a standard rails controller that I would like to edit and be able to keep the current option list selected.

So I have a form that the user has filled out.
Example:
  name(textfield) &
  state(option list)

When the user clicks the edit button, it goes to the generated edit page.  The user has previously selected a name and a state.
The name textfield comes back populated, but the state defaults to the first one in the list.
How can I get my edit method in the controller to pass in the users selected state to the edit view page?

Comment: Can you paste your partial code that contains the form?

Comment: Are you sure the state column is saving to the database?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you have defined your options list but using [options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) and passing a proc to it to conditionally select your options will work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
<%= f.select :project_id, @list, :selected => "user_selected_value"] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be having trouble mass-assigning the field associated with the state drop-down listing. Make sure `attr_accessible` on that attribute is properly set in the model or you will have that attribute assignment ignored when using methods like `new`, `create`, `attributes=` or `update_attributes`.

If that's not the case, then you may be having conflict between string keys in your options and an integer value in the model. Remember that `2` is not the same thing as `"2"` so you should be certain that the keys for your drop-down match the type in question.